# Can we run Java code review rules on scriptlets in jsp pages?

Tags: sonarqube

We have implemented automated code review in our project using SonarQube. We have some legacy application where all the coding was done on JSP pages. We will eventually migrate them to MVC design using Spring, but for now we have to do a code review for the existing java code inside JSP pages.

My question is: can we run Java rules on JSP files? If yes, how do we start with that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot analyze Java code inside JSP files.

Comment: can we have any work around for this, e.g. can we try to look for converted servlet files and run code review on that, is it possible?